# AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'values'

Tags: python

Olá
Eu estou a criar um programa para criar projetos só que ao iniciar o programa a ver se iniciava a janela, onde pergunta a path e o nome do projeto deparei-me com este erro

**Traceback (most recent call last):
File "F:\Projects\Project creator\main.py", line 24, in 
main(main.values)
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'values'**

Eu não sei o que fazer!

Aqui está o meu codigo do ficheiro **main.py**

````
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import criar_pasta

def main(values):
    layout = [
        [sg.Text("Insira o nome do projeto")], [sg.Input(key="nome_do_projeto")],
        [sg.Text("Insira a path do projeto")], [sg.Input(key="path")],
        [sg.Button("Criar ficheiro de programação")], [sg.Button("Cancelar")]
    ]
    window = sg.Window("Project creator", layout=layout)
    while True:
        event, values = window.read()
        if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
            break
        if event == "Cancelar":
            break
        if event == "Criar ficheiro de programação":
            criar_pasta.criar_pasta()

    window.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(values)```
````

Comment: Oproblema está em: `if __name__ == '__main__': main(values)`. Você não inicializou `values`

Comment: Não percebi, é que eu não percebo muito bem sobre modules...
O problema está no `if __name__ == "__main__": main(values)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A variável `values` não é inicializada antes da chamada a `main(...)` na linha 23.

Esse é exatamente o código que vc está executando? A mensagem de erro acusa a linha 24, mas esse código vai até a linha 23 (se contei corretamente).

O erro é compatível com tentar escrever `main.values`, tentando acessar um atributo em uma função.